# How to calculate overtime(OT), when daily OT. weekly OT and Weekend loading is involved

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to interpret an award

Award-(Basically a document issued by the government for minimum wages workers and all of the penalty rates, allowances and rules surrounding it).

So, I have created this worksheet, if I import the timesheet, it would automatically interpret it according to the award.

Most of the rules were within my knowledge about excel but I am now stuck at weekly OT.

Once Weekly Ot kicks in my current interpretation is all out of whack.
So, multiple rules may apply for the same timesheet but we will only choose that with the highest rate.

OT2x > OT 1.5x > Saturday Loading

Condition 1 Daily OT limit is 10 hours. Anything more than 2 hours is 1.5x and anything more that is 2x OT  Monday to Saturday

Condition 2 Weekly Ot Limit is 38 hours. Anything more than 3 hours is 1.5x and anything more that  is 2x OT from Monday to Saturday

[image]

[image]

I have done a screenshot of the current and correct interpretation. Can Someone please help me with this?
Thanks.
Vivek

Comment: Without seeing your current formulas/VBA it is pretty hard to help you. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: Hi Ike, I have added the formulas for the current interpretation. As you can see, there are no logic in the formulas for how the weekly overtime would be calculated and how it would affect this current interpretaion, which is still correct if the weekly overtime doesn't surpass by 40.

Comment: Why is the total base 35 in the correct interpretation. I would have expected 40 ...

Comment: Hi Ike, Apologies, the total weekly hours should be 38. The reason base is only 35 is because when calculating weekly hours all hours are counted towards it regardless of if they working OT. I have also updated the screenshot.